# Batch triangulating a model made of multiple objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

Im very (VERY) new to Blender.
Im in need of triangulating object so I can use them with openGL (Im using .obj files)

I found a tutorial showing how to triangulate using Blender but when I import the obj files I find online I can seem to get all parts of the model into Edit Mode and triangulate everything at once.

When I select all and hit <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> for edit mode, only one part of the model enters Edit Mode.

Is there a better way to triangulate an entire model or do I have to triangulate each part separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

separate objects can be edited one at a time, that is what you are doing now.
if you wish to edit all object at once, you can try to join them (ctrl-j) and then go into edit mode. so:

- select all objects you wish to edit at once (it works only with objects of the same type, eg: meshes and curves can't be joined, without conversion, which probably you don't want to do...)
- press ctrl-j
- you have a single object now, composed of all the vertices, edges, faces jou had before. They are now together in the same object but still not connected yo those previously belonging to other objects

Now you can edit the object at once.

When finished, if you have to separate different objects back, you can:

- select the joined object
- go to edit mode
- deselect everything (A key)
- select only 1 vertex, from one mesh once belonging to a separate object
- select linked vertices, with L key
- separate selected vertices in a separate object, with P key
- repeat until done